# Game of Life C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, conways-game-of-life

Hi I'm currently making a program that find the number of the 'live' cells after the certain generations have been passed. Inputs are:

•first line, the rules of the game as specified above. i.e.: B3/S23 = A cell is "Born" if it has exactly 3 neighbours, "Survives" if it has 2 or 3 living neighbours; it dies otherwise.

•second line, a number i that is the number of iterations the game should progress.

•third line, 2 numbers that are the number of rows(n) and columns(m) in the board.

•n lines (the rows) with m (the colums) characters each. All characters are '#' or '.'

Finally the the board is toroidal. i.e. the left and right sides wrap around and the bottom and top sides wrap around.
And with my codes I am getting bunch of errors that I don't even know about... Plus I don't even know if I am doing it right... Can you guys please help me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
// other includes? Probably yes.
void copy(int m, int n, int array1[m][n], int array2[m][n]){
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++;){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            array2[j][i] = array1[j][i]; 
    }
}
void life(int array[m][n], m, n, string born, survive){
    //Copies the main array to a temp array so changes can be entered into a grid
    //without effecting the other cells and the calculations being performed on them.
    int temp[m][n];
    copy(array, temp);
    for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++){
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            //The Moore neighborhood checks all 8 cells surrounding the current cell in the array.
            int count = 0;
            count = array[j-1][i] + 
                array[j-1][i-1] +
                array[j][i-1] +
                array[j+1][i-1] +
                array[j+1][i] +
                array[j+1][i+1] +
                array[j][i+1] +
                array[j-1][i+1];

            //The cell dies.
            for(int k = 0; k < born.length(); k++;){
                if(count == born[k])
                    temp[j][i] = 1;
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < survive.length(); x++;){
                if(count != survive[k])
                    temp[j][i] = 0;
                if(count == x)
                    temp[j][i] = array[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
    copy(temp, array);
}
bool compare(int array1[m][n], int array2[m][n])
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(array1[j][i]==array2[j][i])
                count++;    
        }
    }
    //Since the count gets incremented every time the cells are exactly the same,
    //an easy way to check if the two arrays are equal is to compare the count to 
    //the dimensions of the array multiplied together.
    if(count == m*n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
// functions? Yep, there should be some.

int main(){
    string variable;
    string i;
    string grid;
    string board;
    getline(cin,variable);
    getline(cin,i);
    getline(cin,grid);
    getline(cin,board);
    auto pos_b= variable.find_first_of("B");
    auto pos_s= variable.find_first_of("S");
    pos_s -= pos_b;//now it's the length of size
    auto b = variable.substr(pos_b+1,pos_s-2);
    auto s = variable.substr(pos_s+1);
    int int_b = stoi(b);
    int int_s = stoi(s);

    cout << int_b << ' ' << int_s << endl;
    auto pos_spc= grid.find_first_of(' ');
    int row = stoi(grid.substr(0,pos_spc));
    int column = stoi(grid.substr(pos_spc+1));
    cout << row << ' ' << column << endl;

    int cnt = 0;
    int gen0[column][row];
    int todo[column][row];
    int backup[column][row];
    for(int j = 1; j < m; j++){
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            if(board[j][i] == '.')
                board[j][i] = 0;
            if(board[j][i] == '#')
                board[j][i] = 1;
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < i; i++){
            if(i == 0)
                copy(gen0, todo, column,row);  
            copy(todo, backup,column,row);          
            print(todo);        
            life(int todo[column][row], column, row, string int_b, int_s);
            cnt++;
        }
    }
}
```

[Test Cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myazt.png)[test cases][2][test cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9f90.png)

Comment: Your "copy" function isn't doing anything, the array created is just a copy

Comment: `int gen0[column][row];` -- This and lines like this are not valid C++.  C++ requires arrays to be declared using constants as the number of items in an array.  Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.  If column or row are large enough, you're risking blowing out the stack, and that is only one of the drawbacks of using arrays like this.

Comment: There are errors in this code, including basic syntax errors. `k++;){` as the increment step of a loop, for example. The `;` shouldn't be there. And the `survive` parameter to `life` has no type. I'd start by fixing your errors, including cranking up warnings to pedantic levels and treating all warnings as errors. Until you pass at least that gauntlet, it is somewhat pointless to do much else (assuming you already worked your algorithm out on paper before writing a line of code).

Comment: for(int j = 1; j <= m; j++) arrays is C++ have indexes from 0 to n - 1, not from 1..n

Comment: Can you put your testcases with input and output in the question directly instead of providing screenshots?